# Comparing numbers in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I set up a Java method that takes new `Measurable` objects, which contain integer values, and adds them to an `ArrayList`. When they are added, each new item is compared against any existing values to determine if the new item should be classified as a "min" number or "max" number. I know that `ArrayLists` can take any data type, so the current formatting of my code is in error. However, I'm not sure how else to compare them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void add(Measurable newItem) {
   list.add(newItem);

   if (min == null || min > newItem) {
      min = newItem;
   }
   else if (newItem > min) {
      max = newItem;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method part for the `max` code should be corrected:

```
public void add(Measurable newItem) {
   list.add(newItem);

   if (min == null || min > newItem) {
      min = newItem;
   }
   if (max == null || newItem > max) {
      max = newItem;
   }
}
```

If `Measurable` class implements `Comparable` interface you can write it as

```
public void add(Measurable newItem) {
   list.add(newItem);

   if (min == null || newItem.compareTo(min) < 0) {
      min = newItem;
   }
   if (newItem.compareTo(max) > 0) {
      max = newItem;
   }
}
```

Comparable example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-comparable-example/)

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code to implement the comparable interface in Measurable. However, when I run my driver, it always assigns the first object in the array to min and max returns "null." Could it be due to the fact that the measurable objects are of type:
public Field(int len, int wid)
and
public Wall(int len, int hgt)

Comment: I am glad you improving the code and make it ready for future extension. If there is only one element in the collection then it is both the `min` and `max` at the same time. So it is correct behavior. If `max` is null then you probably need to add a check  in the `.compareTo` method for argument having null value.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep track of the min and max `Measurable` all the time. This way, you don't need to loop your `list` every time you add a `newItem` but just compare it to these min and max values directly.

**Example**: If `newItem`is less than `currentMin` then `currentMin = newItem`. Same goes for `currentMax`.

Of course you need to implement the "less than" operation because you are dealing with objects. You may use `compareTo()` as suggested by PM 77-1.

Comment: It is what Kevin is doing with max and min.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you comparing each objects of your list? If you want to find the minimum of a list use:

```
min = Collections.min(list,comparator);
```

To find the maximum:

```
max = Collections.max(list,comparator);
```

If you want to compare `measurable`, say for its instance variable int length, create a custom comparator:

```
myComp extends Comparator<measurable>
{
    public int compare(measurable1,measurable2)
    {
        //compare measurable1.length and measurable2.length and return -1,1 or 0 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `min > newItem` with `min.compareTo(newItem) > 0`

Your code suggest that you already track `min` and `max` values of the list. But I think in your code in line

```
else if ( newItem > min) { ...
```

should be

```
else if (max == null || newItem.compareTo(max) > 0) { ...
```